# Problems on .JAR file with JTable and DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtable, defaulttablemodel

i'm developing a desktop app. When i execute my .jar file on another computers, the jframe where i load data into a datatable is not workign correctly. The jre is the same on both computers. The jar works fine on my computer.

Here is the code:

```
public int cargarClaseEnVentanaResultados(ConjuntoResultados conjunto, ControladorVentanaResultados cont){    
    ArrayList<JPanel> jpArray= new ArrayList<>();        


    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;

    String tipoExperimento = new String();
    int contadorVariables = 0;    

    if (!conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().isEmpty()){
        for (int i=0;i<conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().size();i++){
            JTable jtable = new JTable(){
                public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                    return false;   //Disallow the editing of any cell
                }
            };
            jtable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
            jtable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
            jtable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
            JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();  
            jpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            String[] columnNames ={"Variable","Valor"};
            Object[][] data={};
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
            String nombreConjunto = conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getNombreResultado();contadorVariables++;
            jpanel.setName(nombreConjunto);             
            for (int j=0;j<conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().size();j++){
                Object[] o = new Object[2];
                String nombreVar = conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().get(j).getNombre().replace(nombreConjunto+"_", "");
                o[0] = nombreVar;
                if (conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().get(j).getCadena()!=null){
                    o[1] = conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().get(j).getCadena();
                }else if (conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().get(j).getDoble()!=null){
                    o[1] = conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().get(j).getDoble();
                }else if (conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().get(j).getEntero()!=null){
                    o[1] = conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().get(i).getResultados().get(j).getEntero();
                }
                model.addRow(o);
            }   
            jtable.setModel(model);
            jtable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
            JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(jtable);
            jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cont.getVentanaResultados().getjTabbedPane2().getWidth()-50,contadorVariables*altoVentana));
            jpanel.add(tableContainer, c);
            jpArray.add(jpanel);
        }
        for (int k=0;k<jpArray.size();k++){
            aniadirScrollpane(jpArray.get(k), tipoExperimento, cont);
        }
        this.getVentanaResultados().getjTabbedPane2().getSelectedIndex();
    }

    return contadorVariables;
}
```

The only reason i could imagine was the java jre but it's the same. Is there any reason the table wont load? It only shows the headers and it's only loading the last tab.

Thanks!

Comment: how many JTables (and another JComponents) is created inside if (!conjunto.getConjuntoResultados().isEmpty()){ ???

Comment: Where do you get the data from? Database? Local file? Somewhere from the internet?

Comment: @mKorbel It depends on the size of the ConjuntoResultados(), i will creat as much as i need. In this case, i'm creating three

Comment: i'm getting the data from another external jar. I store them on a local class made by me (ConjuntoResultados)

Comment: Can you explain more precicely how you get the data? It seems to me that there is the problem. Because you said the frame and the headline shows but only the table is empty.

Comment: @Thomas Im getting the data from outsise this procedure. It comes from another library already compiled. Im sure im getting the data because the program works okin my pc, such as by eclipse or by executing the .jar file

Comment: @n4h1n Did you try adding `System.out.println(nombre)` before `model.addRow(o)`? This way you could check whether you got the data or not. You have to start it via command line, though. (java -jar <jarname>). Also you assumed that the error comes from the JRE. Did you try `java -version` on both PCs?

Comment: I found out the origin of the problem. I'm collecting the data after executing an .exe file wich is includded in a library i generated. I think the problem is that the process builder is not building correctly the procces and it's not being launched